# Can't select a drop down in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm trying to automate selecting a dropdown in selenium ide, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Basically, I record a click on the menu item, which reveals the drop down, but whenever I use the click command on one of the options, it closes the menu without ever selecting the new option. I've also tried the select command but I keep getting "specified element is not a select"

any ideas?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.

Here's the Selenese:

      select, 
   id=id=simulationsTabView:calibrateModelForm:marketEnvCombo_label
   Official Market Def

Here's the HTML:

<select   
     id="simulationsTabView:calibrateModelForm:marketEnvCombo_input"
  name="simulationsTabView:calibrateModelForm:marketEnvCombo_input" tabindex="-1">
<option selected="selected">
</option><option value="32">Official Market Def</option>
</select>

Here's the error message:

   [error] Specified element is not a Select (has no options)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selenium should be returning a single action when interacting with HTML select elements.

For example, if I had the following select element

```
<select name="numbers">
   <option value="One">1</option>
   <option value="Two">2</option>
   <option value="Three">3</option>
</select>
```

And selected "2", selenium should return a single action.

```
 | Command       | Target       | Value     |
 | select        | name=numbers | label=Two |
```

If the IDE is not recording the event, you may be running into another issue such as the element being defined as hidden. Without additional details though, it's really hard to say.

Comment: I had the same issue like Sean, got it to work with your answer, thank you!
Selenium recorded the option's name and value of the default element, so I had to change the value-field value to the label of the option's element!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the page and view source. The drop down options should be listed. Also the target name. You can then manually create the command. Don't do the first Item in the list. Pick like the third one first and test.

Once you have a single one working cut and paste it into notepad. Get the listing from the View Source and copy the line replacing the value. Copy and paste back in to Selenium on the Source tab.